# Can a superuser (with 'root' access) manipulate data on a database installed on the server?

Tags: root

I am inquiring as to what access a user with the 'root' password on a Linux server has.  On this server, a database is installed.  If someone logs into 'root' do they now have full control (the ability to read, modify, delete, execute) data within that database?

Thank you kindly for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer **yes**: root can impersonate any account and read everything is not encrypted.